# Avery 5160 label definition does not print properly

Tags: address-labels

WHen printing Avery 5160 labels, the printing does not fit the labels properly.

That is, the top line of the top row of labels is at the right place, but for each row after that, the top row is down a little bit; the printing on the bottom row of labels goes down off the page.

Same with the left margins - the 1st column is at the proper left margin, but the 2nd and 3rd columns move too close to the left edge of the label.

We've fiddled with the settings, but nothing seems to work.

The user has printed 5160 labels on the same printer, from Word, very successfully.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: When you say you've fiddled with the settings, have you tried just creating a new label type with different margins? e.g. at Admin - Communications - Label Formats? You can look at the 5160 one to see what they're currently set to.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried those particular labels, but I had a similar problem with Avery J8160 labels. I started off with a MS Word template downloaded from Avery to get all the spacing values, but had to make some adjustments to the label format, which I did by trial and error to get it printing correctly. I calculated the horizontal spacing as 0.25 cm but had to use 0.45 cm and for vertical spacing@ Calculated 0 cm but had ti use  0.15 cm. Will be different values for your labels buy that gives you the idea. I don't know what wasn't right, but this solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you.  Did create a copy of 5160 and tried/tried/tried unsuccessfully adjusting spacing values.  Ended up putting label data into a .CSV file, exporting, merging with a Word template for the labels and printing.  I think if you stay with the default 11 point font, the CiviCRM template works, but using a larger font makes the lines run over and  disrupts the spacing.  Why this happens in CiviCRM but not in Word is still a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

When you print the labels, are you sure that you are printing them at 100% scale (or "Actual size"), and not to "Fit"?

I tested CiviCRM by using the following steps:

- I downloaded the Avery template Avery5160EasyPeelAddressLabels.doc, opened it in Word and saved it as PDF to get the "official" label outlines in a PDF file.
- I created some mailing labels in CiviCRM, set to Avery 5160.
- I superimposed the Avery label outlines PDF onto the CiviCRM mailing labels PDF using https://tools.pdf24.org "PDF Overlay"

Result - all addresses are well within the Avery template-derived label outlines. The below image is a screenshot of my resulting PDF:

[image: Avery label outlines (from official Avery template) overlaid on CiviCRM-produced address labels]

Some of the dimensions in the CiviCRM label configuration (Administer > Communication > Label formats) are slightly different to the dimensions that can be derived from the Word template text boxes' sizes and positions but not enough to cause a problem.

So I think you have a scaling problem when you print. Check the scaling setting when you print, and try a different PDF reader if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I found that 5160 appears in both "Label Vendors" of "Avery US", and "Label Vendors" of "Avery A4/A5".  If your printer is a US printer, you must us the Avery US vendor.  If you use the Avery A4/A5, your merge will indicate that it's gone to the queue and printed, but you won't be able to find it, and it won't print or be in the queue.